# AutoNumbering in Visio and PPT

Tags: macros, powerpoint, visio, autonumber

Is there a way to autonumber when you open up visio or ppt? I need a number to count on the slide in ppt and in a shape in visio. I have tried insert excel that has a macro that will do what I want it to do but I can't get it to work when you open up visio/ppt. All I want is a number count to display when I open up the document.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in PowerPoint:

1. Insert > Header/Footer...
2. Check the `Slide Numbers` box.

Comment: but will it do it auto when opening up ppt?

Comment: Are you referring to adding numbers to an unnumbered presentation? The only way to do that would be with a VBA macro.

Comment: ok.. any thoughts on how to do that. I have written them in Word and Excel. Was able to do that because I had a place to insert them. Not so much in Visio and ppt. I can create that macro but it's adding the trigger on where the number should go, that's my real problem

Answer (score 0):

PowerPoint doesn't have any mechanism for running code automatically in response to a user opening a document file.  You pretty much need to write an add-in that traps and responds to events like users opening a file, and the add-in must be installed on each user's PC where you expect this to work.

Answer (score 0):

For Visio, this this MSDN Article:
[**Visio: How to Use Background Pages to Set Up Automatic Page Numbering**](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/254629) may be of assistance.